# how to debug target from administrator with remote SSH vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

I'm wondering how to instruct vscode to launch debugging executable on target (Windows) with admin priveledge while debugging with remote SSH extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is easy way to do that, you have only permissions that the account you login into have, so vscode can't launch debug session with more permissions then it has.

You could try to start debugging session with terminal using something like `sudo` *(or windows equivalent)* to elevate your permissions and then attach vscode debugger to already running process, but it isn't always possible.